# MVC ActionResult isn't grabbing Where expression correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, actionresult

I'm working on an animal shelter application.  I have an AnimalInitializer.cs in my DAL and I have it broken down into dogs and cats by species.  In my controller, I want to see the list of dogs for one ActionResult and a list of cats for another ActionResult.  They are all returning as dogs when I run the ShowDogs view and nothing is returned on the ShowCats view.

Pet model:

```
public enum SpeciesType { Dog, Cat }

public class Pet 
{
    public SpeciesType SpeciesType { get; set; }
}
```

AnimalInitializer seed:

```
var dogs = new List<Dog>
{
     new Dog { SpeciesType = SpeciesType.Dog, Breed = "German Shepherd" }
}

var Cats = new List<Cat>
{
    new Cat { SpeciesType = SpeciesType.Cat, Breed = "Domestic Long Haired" },
}
```

PetController:

```
public ActionResult ShowDogs()
    {
        var dogs = db.Pets.Where(d => d.SpeciesType == SpeciesType.Dog);
        return View(dogs.ToList());
    }

public ActionResult ShowCats()
    {
        var cats = db.Pets.Where(c => c.SpeciesType == SpeciesType.Cat);
        return View(cats.ToList());
    }
```

ShowDogs View:

```
@model IEnumerable<AnimalShelter1.Models.Pet>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Breed)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SpeciesType)
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Breed)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SpeciesType)
    </td>
</tr>           
}

</table>
```

ShowCats View:

```
@model IEnumerable<AnimalShelter1.Models.Pet>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SpeciesType)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Breed)
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SpeciesType)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Breed)
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

[image: ShowDogs view]

[image: ShowCats view]

Comment: Are both `ShowDogs` and `ShowCats` views are nearly identical where `ShowCats` not return any results? I can't see anything wrong in your current example, please provide more details.

Comment: Yes, both views are identical, I updated my question to reflect the views.  Would a screenshot of the program running, help?

Comment: You can provide screenshot for both views as proof of the problem. Since both query and view codes are nearly identical, `ShowCats` should also returns iterated result set from `SpeciesType.Cat` criteria, and the problem may occurs somewhere other than controllers or views.

Comment: Are you sure you have cats in your database??? Also, can you debug and see if you're getting cat objects in your actionresult???

Comment: Well... I see your screenshot and found that all `"Domestic Long Haired"` entries have `SpeciesType.Dog`. Are you actually have any table entries that has `SpeciesType.Cat`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether the below solution works. But please try this:

```
public ActionResult ShowDogs()
{
    var dogs = db.Pets.Where(d => d.SpeciesType == SpeciesType.Dog).ToList();
    return View(dogs);
}

public ActionResult ShowCats()
{
    var cats = db.Pets.Where(c => c.SpeciesType == SpeciesType.Cat).ToList();
    return View(cats);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing changed when I made your change suggestion.  Thank you for your suggestion, though!

Comment: Okay, then please keep breakpoint in your ShowCats() action and then check whether "var cats" is receiving value or not.

Comment: if the data is present in the var cats you have problem with your view else check if there is data in the database with category cat.

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up editing the ones that were supposed to be cats and saving them and that seemed to have worked.  Every time I launch the application, the animals are in their correct places, and the breakpoints for ShowDogs and ShowCats are both getting hit and populated with the correct animals.  Weird, I don't know what went wrong with it...